# How to test Facebook-Connect on local host using ssl

Tags: facebook, ssl, oauth, omniauth

I have a rails app that uses facebook connect to enable user registration/login (using devise and omniauth).  After reading several articles on Firesheep i decided to force ssl communications for my entire app.

I followed this tutorial to force my rails 3.0.x app to communicate only via ssl: http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2011/05/configuring-rails-3-https-ssl/

And I followed this tutorial so that I could test the app locally using webrick on locahost:3001: http://blog.readypulse.com/2012/01/19/setup-webrick-to-serve-ssl-https-as-well-as-non-ssl-http-traffic-side-by-side/

So far so good.  My app forces ssl communications throughout while running on `localhost:3000`.  My problem occurs when trying to communicate with facebook connect

If I change my facebook development app's site url to `https://localhost:3001`, fb graph responds with 
 `{
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 191
   }
}`

However, if I change the site url to `http:localhost:3001` I get an error from my server saying that the connection was reset while loading the page.  My browser URL bar shows that the url it tried to load was `localhost:3001/auth/facebook/callback?code=MYCODEHERE`, and if I simply add, "https://" in front of that URL and reload, the page loads as expected.

Maybe my issue stems from my very basic knowledge of SSL.  but i would greatly appreciate it if someone can explain to me how to setup a facebook development app to support my local testing of facebook connect over ssl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK.  Got it working.  Here's what I did so that I can test fb and twitter registration/login over ssl on localhost:3001.

First, I set my app's FB site url to `http://localhost:3001`.  Then I modified the omniauth initializer as follows:

```
if RAILS_ENV == "production"
  full_host = 'https://www.mydomain.com'
  Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :facebook, 'myfbappid', 'myfbsecret', {:scope => 'email, publish_stream'}
    provider :twitter, 'mytwitterappid', 'mytwittersecret'
  end
  Twitter.configure do |config|
    config.consumer_key = 'myconsumerkey'
    config.consumer_secret = 'myconsumersecret'
    config.oauth_token =    'myoauthtoken'
    config.oauth_token_secret = 'myoauthtokensecret'
  end
elsif RAILS_ENV == "development"
  full_host = 'https://localhost:3001'
  Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :facebook, 'myfbdevappid', 'myfbdefappsecret', {:scope => 'email, publish_stream'}
    provider :twitter, 'mytwitterdevappid', 'mytwitterdevappsecret'
  end
  Twitter.configure do |config|
    config.consumer_key = 'mytwitterconsumerkey'
    config.consumer_secret = 'mytwitterconsumersecret'
    config.oauth_token =    'mytwitteroauthtoken'
    config.oauth_token_secret = 'mytwitteroathtokensecret'
  end
end
OmniAuth.config.full_host = full_host
```

Comment: I needed to use `Rails.env == "development"` instead of `RAILS_ENV == "development"` .

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup a subdomain pointing to your localhost (`whatever IN A 127.0.0.1`) or create said subdomain via your `/etc/hosts` file.

In both cases you can then use `http://yoursubdomain.yourdomain/auth/....` with `yourdomain` being the domain registered for the facebook app.

Comment: not sure I get this.  I don't use any subdomains.  I simply want FB graph to call back using https.

Comment: Facebook only allows a return URL that matches the domain you registered for your app. So you need to give it an url that is either the domain you entered in the app settings or a subdomain of it. Since you are working on localhost you need a DNS/hosts entry to give you such a subdomain instead of `localhost`.

Comment: Ahh.  I get what you're saying. However, I went a different route (which I should've mentioned in my first post).  I have one FB app for development (which currently has a site url of http://locahost:3000), and a separate FB app for production (which points to www.myapp.com).  My problem is that I can't get the FB development app to call-back to `https://localhost:3001`.  It wants to simply call back to `http://localhost:3001`.

Comment: Ah, try settings the site url to `localhost`. If that doesn't work or it completely ignores the port, you might have to switch to port 443.

Comment: Getting frustrated, but i'm thankful for your help, ThiefMaster.  FB wouldn't let me use your first suggestion, saying that I had to pre-pend either "http" or "https".  Second suggestion resulted in the same, FB graph error, `{ "error": { "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.", "type": "OAuthException", "code": 191 } }`.  I got this same error if I used a site url of `https://locahost`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://ngrok.com/ to get a secure url which point to your localhost